# SSIS - how can I split an XML record into multiple records with different values for each column?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, integration

I have the following XML Source File:

```
<documents>
<document fileNo='1234'>
<item name='EmployerEmail'><text>BarryBlue@Blue.Inc</text></item>
<item name='EmployerForename'><text>Barry</text></item>
<item name='EmployerSurname'><text>Blue</text></item>
<item name='EmployeeEmail'><text>Gary</text></item>
<item name='EmployeeForename'><text>Green</text></item>
<item name='EmployeeSurname'><text>GarryGreen@Blue.Inc</text></item>
</document>
```

I want to export this record into an excel file as two separate records for the employer and employee. So my end result would look like this:

[image]

I have gotten as far as being able to export the above as a single record with 8 columns. But I'm not sure how to separate them in to two record of 5 columns each.

I am using dataflows in SSIS so if it can be done with dataflows that would be ideal. But if code is the only way I can work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, T-SQL and XQuery based solution.

**SQL**

```sql
    DECLARE @xml XML =
    N'<documents>
        <document fileNo="1234">
            <item name="EmployerEmail">
                <text>BarryBlue@Blue.Inc</text>
            </item>
            <item name="EmployerForename">
                <text>Barry</text>
            </item>
            <item name="EmployerSurname">
                <text>Blue</text>
            </item>
            <item name="EmployeeEmail">
                <text>GarryGreen@Blue.Inc</text>
            </item>
            <item name="EmployeeForename">
                <text>Gary</text>
            </item>
            <item name="EmployeeSurname">
                <text>Green</text>
            </item>
        </document>
    </documents>';
    
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT @@SPID)) AS Nmbr 
       , @xml.value('(/documents/document/@fileNo)[1]','INT') AS fileNo
       , LEFT(c.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(30)'), 8) AS Type
       , c.value('(/documents/document/*[sql:column("seq.pos")]/text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS Email
       , c.value('(/documents/document/*[sql:column("seq.pos") + 1]/text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS FirstName
       , c.value('(/documents/document/*[sql:column("seq.pos") + 2]/text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS LastName
       , seq.pos   -- just to see
    FROM @xml.nodes('/documents/document/*[position() mod 3 = 1]') AS t(c)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.c.value('let $n := . return count(/documents/document/*[. << $n[1]]) + 1','INT') AS pos
             ) AS seq;
```

**Output**

| Nmbr | fileNo | Type | Email | FirstName | LastName | pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | Employer | BarryBlue@Blue.Inc | Barry | Blue | 1 |
| 2 | 1234 | Employee | GarryGreen@Blue.Inc | Gary | Green | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

Resolved myself.

I added a multicast to two pivot tables, then used Union All to combine them and outputted to an excel file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).